# Undeclared Identifier -NSBackgroundActivityScheduler

Tags: ios, objective-c

when i'm tried to use NSBackgroundActivityScheduler , getting an Undeclared Identifier Error.Should i import some framework?Any help?

This is my code :

```
NSBackgroundActivityScheduler *activity = [[NSBackgroundActivityScheduler alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"com.example.MyApp.updatecheck"];
```

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSBackgroundActivityScheduler` is available under macOS only (not for iOS).

See [Apple documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbackgroundactivityscheduler?language=objc).

Answer (score 0):

```
    for iOS
Use timer in Swift
    var timer = Timer()
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
         timeInterval: 1.0,
         target: self,
         selector: #selector(self.callFunction),
         userInfo: nil,
         repeats: true)
    //time interval is in seconds

    func callFunction(){
    //this method will be called repeatedly after every 1 sec 
    }

    timer.invalidate() //to stop timer
```